# Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Isolated' was not found

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

We are using powershell to automate app services deployment.

Until today this code used to work fine:

```
New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-SouthCentralUS" -Name ($appName + "-" + $dirTrailer) -Location "South Central US" -AppServicePlan $serverFarm
$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name ($appName + "-" + $dirTrailer)
```

Currently the `Get-AzureWebsite` cmdlet is erroring with

```
Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Isolated' was not found.
```

We were using azure powershell version 3.0.0 but we're getting the same error after upgrading to 4.3.1.

Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want **[`Get-AzureRmWebApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/Get-AzureRmWebApp?view=azurermps-4.3.1)** and not `Get-AzureWebsite` which is an [ASM-era](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model) cmdlet and has no clue about Isolated App Service Plans (aka ASEv2).

Comment: I thought so, I was expecting the Get-AzureWebsite cmdlet would keep working and hide the all the complexity internally. If the authors won't fix the cmdlet to do so in a week I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.